# DBSCAN - Space complexity of O(n)?

Tags: clustering, scalability, dbscan

According to Wikipedia, "the distance matrix of size $\frac{(n^2-n)}{2}$ can be materialized to avoid distance recomputations, but this needs $O(n^2)$ memory, whereas a non-matrix based implementation of DBSCAN only needs $O(n)$ memory."

$\frac{(n^2-n)}{2}$ is basically the triangular matrix. However, it says that a non-matrix based implementation only requires $O(n)$ memory. How does that work? Regardless of what data structure you use, don't you always have to have $\frac{(n^2-n)}{2}$ distance values? It would still be $O(n^2)$ space complexity, no? Is there something I'm missing here? I'm working with a huge dataset and I would really like to cut down on memory usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run DBSCAN without storing the distances in a matrix. This has the drawback that each time you visit a point, you have to recalculate all the relevant distances, which requires more time. However, the space complexity stays $O(n)$, since the only things you have in memory at any single time are the positions of the n points, their various labels, the neighbors of the current point and the neighbors of a particular neighbour in the case that the point turns out to be a core point.

Comment: It does not increase the "time *complexity*". 2 times O(n²) is the same complexity as O(n²). It could increase the runtime roughly 2 fold (assuming you do not have an index, and ignoring memory caches), but that is the same asymptotic "complexity".

Comment: It's worth noting that there exist indexes that try to avoid computing all O(n) distances for each point.

Comment: Yes @Anony-Mousse, you are correct! The asymptotic behavior of complexity (which is what is commonly meant by "time complexity") remains the same (unless you use some indexing structure as you also note). I was using the term in a relaxed manner, meaning that you have a significant time burden due to the repeated computation of the same distances. I will correct the sentence. :)

Comment: Is there an option to do so with the sklearn implementation or any other implementation?